# Парсинг регулярным выражением с заменой текста

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Требуется сделать в неком html коде замену выражения

```
|img id="test" class="test2" alt="test3"|
```

на выражение

```
|div id="test" class="test2"| test3 |/div|
```

test1, test2, test3 - любой, текст который перенесётся в div. Возможно ещё как-то при помощи функции exec().

Если возможно, то аналог бы на php для preg_replace(). Ну и хотелось бы понять вариант обратного преобразования второго выражения в первое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = '|img id="test" class="test2" alt="test3"|';
alert(str.replace(/\|img([^\|]*)alt="([^"]*)"([^\|]*)\|/, '|div$1|$2|/div|'));
```

Comment: Красиво, и работает хорошо. Но вот ещё вопрос, далее требуется использовать в замене test, из поля id не получается его выделить.

Comment: Решил самостоятельно...

Answer (score 0):

[string.replace()](http://javascript.ru/String/replace) - то, что вы ищете.